# Something wrong: LaTeX with listings

Tags: listings

I'm trying to get green comments and blue javadocs.

But with this code I can't get blue javadocs, always I get all comments green:

```
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gray97}{gray}{.97}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{.75}
\definecolor{gray45}{gray}{.45}

\definecolor{red}{rgb}{0.6,0,0} % strings
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0.25,0.5,0.35} % comments
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.5,0,0.35} % keywords
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0.25,0.35,0.75} % doc

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset {
frame               =   Ltb,
framerule           =   0pt,
aboveskip           =   0.5cm,
framextopmargin     =   3pt,
framexbottommargin  =   3pt,
framexleftmargin    =   0.4cm,
framesep            =   0pt,
rulesep             =   .4pt,
backgroundcolor     =   \color{gray97},
rulesepcolor        =   \color{black},
%
stringstyle         =   \color{red},
showstringspaces    =   false,
basicstyle          =   \ttfamily\small,
commentstyle        =   \color{green},
morecomment         =   [s][\color{blue}]{/**}{*/},
keywordstyle        =   \color{purple}\bfseries,
%
numbers             =   left,
numbersep           =   15pt,
numberstyle         =   \tiny,
numberfirstline     =   false,
breaklines          =   true,
}
```

I use this code to print the code example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
    /* Includes */
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        puts("Hola mundo!"); // Text console
    }
\end{lstlisting}
```

In that can I be wrong? Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because selecting `language=C` is overriding your `morecomment` setting. As the listings documentation says:

> Please remember that both "extra" comments must be defined after the normal comment,
>   since the delimiter `/*` is a substring of `/*+` and `/*-`.

To fix it, either set the language in the `\lstset` before setting `morecomment`, set the `morecomment` value when you use the `lstlisting` environment, or define a style for your settings which you apply after setting the language (e.g. `\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,style=mystyle]`)

Comment: ¡Thank you very much! I'm new with LaTeX and that error was driving me crazy :D